# Create mySQL BEFORE/AFTER UPDATE trigger

Tags: mysql

Trying to understand how to make a trigger in mysql to automatically set a value in a record field.  Not even sure if I need a `BEFORE` or `AFTER` trigger.

I have a table with one field named `date_created` and another `date_updated`, both of type `datetime`.  The `date_created` field is set to NOT NULL and default to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. The `date_updated` field is currently set to NULL, but I can change that if needed.

Whenever a new record is created, the `date_created` field gets filled automatically. This way I can omit the field from an input `FORM`.

Now whenever the record gets updated, I'd like for the `date_updated` field to be filled-in automatically - for **any** subsequent updates.

I've tried several versions but keep getting errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a trigger for this case. Use `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Read this manual page for details: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/timestamp-initialization.html